# Caliper @Param not working

Tags: java, microbenchmark, caliper

I am trying to use the `@Param` annotation on a field with the command line args of the form: "-Dmyparamname=val1,val2,val3" and it is not working.  I am using caliper-0.5-rc1.jar.  My actual usage looks like:

```
java -classpath "mylongclasspath" MyBenchmarkClass -Jjit=-client,-server -Dprovider=CGLIB,JAVASSIST,JAVAPROXY
```

My benchmark class has the following:

```
public class MyBenchmarkClass extends SimpleBenchmark {
    @Param
    private String provider;

    ...
}
```

But when I run I am only getting options for the jit, but not for the -Dprovider:

```
 0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=M1, jit=-server} 30.40 ns; ?=0.13 ns @ 3 trials
 17% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=M2, jit=-server} 31.42 ns; ?=0.08 ns @ 3
```

etc., eventually repeating all benchmarks with "jit=-client"

I would have expected to see:

```
 0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=M1, jit=-server provider=CGLIB} ...etc.
```

I have tried all sorts of options: including quotes around the values in the command arg, providing them as a static field of type List internally, etc.  There is never any indication that it is attempting to iterate over supplied values of "provider".

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the 0.5-rc1 build (the only thing in Maven Central) is the problem.  I swiped a preliminary 1.0 build from another project (I didn't want to have to download the whole project and Maven and build it).